# Multi-line Pattern and tag search

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I'm trying to make a pattern for tags, but the sub method just replaces the first char and 3 at the end of the line, im trying to replace all tags on the line and with multiline

```
p=re.compile('<img=([^}]*)>([^}]*)</img>', re.S)
p.sub(r'[img=\1]\2[/img]','<img="test">dsad</img> <img="test2">dsad2</img>')
output:
'**[**img="test">dsad</img> <img="test2"]dsad2**[/img]**'
```

Comment: Use the [`bbcode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbcode) library instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You're using towards the start of your re's pattern:

```
<img=([^}]*)>
```

this will gobble up (as group 1) all characters after the leading `<img=`, **including other tags!!!**, up to the last `>` it can possibly gobble; `*` is GREEDY -- it gobbles up as much as it possibly can. Not sure why you're specifically excluding closed-braces `}`? Maybe you meant to exclude closed angular brackets instead (`>`).

For NON-greedy matching, instead of `*`, you need `*?`; with that, you'll be gobbling up as little as you can, instead of as much as you can.  So, I think you mean:

```
p = re.compile(r'<img=([^>]*?)>(.*?)</img>', re.S)
```

this matches one `img` tag (and all tags inside it), and appears to be performing exactly the substitutions you mean.

Comment: Thanks, this solve the problem

i didnt find good documentation/manuals about patterns, even u understood better your explanation than some sites...

Comment: do you know how make the inverse?

p = re.compile(r'[img=([^]]*?)](.*?)[/img]', re.S)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\re.py", line 241, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis